# TFS Selenium XPaths

Tags: selenium, xpath, tfs

Hello I am trying to set up a selenium IDE script that clicks on each repository in the admin area and edits some permissions.

[image: Admin Area]

I can have it simply click on the ID of the repo but the issue I have with that is the ID assigns a number to the repo which while it works it is not great as that every time I add a new repo to our TFS I'll have to fix all the repo IDs since they'll be off by 1. I am trying to have Selenium click on a repo by it's title or it's link I had some progress with using:

```
click link=My.Repo.TFS
```

The issue with that is when it executes the command it kind of clicks on the link. Normally when a a link is clicked in the admin area of TFS it will expand the repo and show the branches for the repo, but with the command I have now it simply highlights the linked link but does not expand it.

This is what the command does

[image: Partial Selection]

This is what it should do

[image: Full Selection]

Edit: As requested here are some screenshots to better show what I mean.

Comment: What's the detail  position "Clicks on each repository in the admin area"? Did you mean the admin page in TFS web portal or something else? Could you add some related screenshot to make it more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
    ChromeDriver cd = new ChromeDriver();
    cd.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://xxxxxx.visualstudio.com/GitPullRequest/_admin/_versioncontrol");
    cd.FindElementByXPath("//div[text() = 'aaa']").Click();
```

And then you will get a result as below:
[image]